# Bouncy Castle - how to get Public Key Info from JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key

I have the following code to extract Private Key

```
    PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded)));
    Object object = parser.readObject();
    PEMDecryptorProvider provider = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder()
            .build(props.getProperty(KeytoolFlags.KEYPASS.name()).toCharArray());

    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
        KeyPair pair = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(provider));
        return loadPublic ? pair.getPublic() : pair.getPrivate();
    } else if (object instanceof PEMKeyPair) {
        return loadPublic ? converter.getPublicKey(((PEMKeyPair) (object)).getPublicKeyInfo())
                : converter.getPrivateKey(((PEMKeyPair) (object)).getPrivateKeyInfo());
    } else {
        InputDecryptorProvider p2 = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder()
                .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                .build(props.getProperty(KeytoolFlags.KEYPASS.name()).toCharArray());
        return converter.getPrivateKey(((PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) object).decryptPrivateKeyInfo(p2));
    }
```

I would like to get the Public Key from converter when it's `JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder`. Is there any way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, although it feels rather ugly to me, is to convert the private key 'back' to one of OpenSSL's 'legacy' forms, which `PEMParser` is then able to turn into a `PEMKeyPair` with both halves, from which the public can be selected. Otherwise, the method must be tailored depending on the key algorithm aka type, but can be more efficient which I like better. Here are both options for your consideration:

```
public static void SO57043669PKCS8_Public_BC (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object p8e = new PEMParser (new FileReader (args[0])).readObject();
    // for PKCS8-encrypted result is org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo 
    PrivateKeyInfo p8i = ((PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo)p8e).decryptPrivateKeyInfo(
            new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(args[1].toCharArray()) );
    // or get org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo directly from PEMParser for PKCS8-clear
    PublicKey pub = null;
    if( args.length>=3 ){ // the simple way:
        PrivateKey prv = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(p8i);
        PemObject old = new JcaMiscPEMGenerator (prv,null).generate();
        StringWriter w1 = new StringWriter(); 
        PemWriter w2 = new PemWriter(w1);
        w2.writeObject(old); w2.close();
        Object pair = new PEMParser(new StringReader(w1.toString())).readObject();
        pub = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair)pair).getPublic();
    }else{
        ASN1ObjectIdentifier id = p8i.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm().getAlgorithm();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec p8s = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec (p8i.getEncoded());
        if( id.equals(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption) ){
            // the standard PKCS1 private key format for RSA redundantly includes e
            KeyFactory rfact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPrivateCrtKey rprv = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rfact.generatePrivate(p8s);
            // or JcaPEMKeyConverter.getPrivateKey does the same thing
            pub = /*(RSAPublicKey)*/ rfact.generatePublic(
                    new RSAPublicKeySpec (rprv.getModulus(), rprv.getPublicExponent()));
        }else if( id.equals(X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_dsa) ){
            // the apparently ad-hoc format OpenSSL uses for DSA does not include y but it can be computed
            KeyFactory dfact = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
            DSAPrivateKey dprv = (DSAPrivateKey) dfact.generatePrivate(p8s);
            // or JcaPEMKeyConverter.getPrivateKey does the same thing
            BigInteger p = dprv.getParams().getP(), q = dprv.getParams().getQ(), g = dprv.getParams().getG();
            pub = /*(DSAPublicKey)*/ dfact.generatePublic (
                    new DSAPublicKeySpec(g.modPow(dprv.getX(),p), p, q, g) );
            // warning: naive computation probably vulnerable to sidechannel attack if any  
        }else if( id.equals(X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_ecPublicKey) ){
            // the SECG SEC1 format for EC private key _in PKCS8 by OpenSSL_ 
            // includes []] BITSTR(Q) (but not [0] params which is already in the PKCS8 algid)
            org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.ECPrivateKey eprv = org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.ECPrivateKey.getInstance(p8i.parsePrivateKey());
            byte[] eenc = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo (p8i.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm(), eprv.getPublicKey().getOctets()).getEncoded(); 
            KeyFactory efact = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            pub = /*(ECPublicKey)*/ KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(eenc));
            //}else if maybe others ...
        }else throw new Exception ("unknown private key OID " + id);
    }
    System.out.println (pub.getAlgorithm() + " " + pub.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: uniquely done! Thanks. For now I think I will try and use the public key separately. The reason for this is that we are loading the keys from DB. We have two variants - JKS and PKCS8 (PEM encoded). I was hoping that saving a private key entry should be sufficient. but looks like for PKCS8 format keys are meant to be kept as public and private keys separately. I will go with that approach for now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, here's a way to convert Ed25519 private keys to public keys.

Edit: As @tytk notes in the comments, given a `BCEdDSAPrivateKey`, you can just call `getPublicKey()`. I am not entirely sure if it's possible to obtain a private `EdDSAKey` that wouldn't be `BCEdDSAPrivateKey`, using BC or otherwise, but just in case I'm leaving an alternative codepath that works.

```kotlin
private val bouncyCastleProvider = BouncyCastleProvider()
private val pkcs8pemKeyConverter = JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(bouncyCastleProvider)

fun makeKeyPair(keyReader: Reader, passphrase: CharArray): KeyPair {
    var obj = PEMParser(keyReader).readObject()
    ...
    if (obj is PrivateKeyInfo) {
        val privateKey = pkcs8pemKeyConverter.getPrivateKey(obj)

        when (privateKey) {
            is BCEdDSAPrivateKey -> return KeyPair(privateKey.publicKey, privateKey)
            is EdDSAKey -> return KeyPair(genEd25519publicKey(privateKey, obj), privateKey)
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}

private fun genEd25519publicKey(privateKey: EdDSAKey, privateKeyInfo: PrivateKeyInfo): PublicKey {
    val privateKeyRaw = ASN1OctetString.getInstance(privateKeyInfo.parsePrivateKey()).octets
    val privateKeyParameters = Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters(privateKeyRaw)
    val publicKeyParameters = privateKeyParameters.generatePublicKey()
    val spi = SubjectPublicKeyInfo(privateKeyInfo.privateKeyAlgorithm, publicKeyParameters.encoded)
    val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privateKey.algorithm, bouncyCastleProvider)
    return factory.generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(spi.encoded))
}
```

Comment: if `privateKey` is an instance of `EdDSAPrivateKey` then you can call `getPublicKey()`.

Comment: @tytk Weirdest thing, a few hours ago I randomly run into an issue with the above code (I have a strong suspicion that it's incorrect!) and about at the same time you post a comment that actually helps me. What a timing... I'll be trying to understand what exactly is wrong with the code